# Heavy-oxygen water melting and boiling points

Tags: water, isotopes

What is heavy-oxygen water (O-17 and O-18, both if possible) melting and boiling points?

I already search it on the web, but the only result I can get is this one: [http://www.chemicalbook.com](http://www.chemicalbook.com/ChemicalProductProperty_EN_CB7334306.htm). They do not provide any source nor reference, and the small amount of information they give do not make sense to me.

Comment: Have you tried the CRC handbook of chemistry and physics?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Is it available on-line (at least this small bit of information)? I don't have access to a written copy without taking a plane (I live in an small island).

Comment: [It's available](http://www.hbcpnetbase.com/), but may require subscription.

Comment: One could extract it out of data in "Liquid-vapor fractionation of oxygen and hydrogen isotopes of water from the freezing to the critical temperature", Juske Horit and David J. Weslowski, Geochimica et Cosmochimica Acta 58(16) 3425-3427 (1994).

Comment: @JonCuster As abstract says, it only cover range from 25ºC to 100ºC, so it only answers half of my question (boiling point). Melting point is still an unknown, and sadly it's the one I'm more interested on.

Comment: They combined their data with literature to get the fractionation curves from 0 to 350C. The differences in melting and freezing can be extracted from thermidynamics. This is left as an exercise...